# What is the preferred knot for cinching a hard item to your car rack?

Tags: knots

Let's say I want to tie a hard object to the top of my car, like a kayak.  **What is the preferred knot for cinching it down tightly?**

I often run into this problem with boats, lumber, and the like.  In the past, I've used a tautline hitch with success, but I've heard that it's not safe under critical loads.  I've also used a trucker's hitch several times, and that seemed to work well, but I'm not sure what the norm is.

Comment: If you find your trucker's hitch difficult to undo, see this answer to a related question: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5673/which-mid-line-knot-is-best-suited-for-a-truckers-hitch/5687#5687

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The knot(s) I would use are:

- [Bowline](http://www.animatedknots.com/bowline/) knot to one side of the rack
- Throw line over object, under rack, then back over object.
- Use [truckers hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/truckers/index.php?Categ=household&LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com), backed up with 2-3 [reversing half hitches](http://www.animatedknots.com/halfhitch/index.php?Categ=basics&LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com).
- If there is a lot of slack, make a [daisy chain](http://www.animatedknots.com/chainsinnet/index.php?LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com) and tie off with a [fisherman's](http://www.animatedknots.com/doublefishermans/index.php?LogoImage=LogoGrog.jpg&Website=www.animatedknots.com)

Make sure to perform this process for the front and the back of the object.

Check that the object doesn't shift, and recheck each couple hours of driving.

Comment: +1 for the trucker's hitch. I've yet to find a load that couldn't be wrangled with a truckers and a couple of half-hitches.

Comment: @Dangeranger, it's been two years since you gave me this advice and I've used the trucker's hitch countless times since. Thanks for introducing me to it ;)

Comment: @MikeM.Lin glad I could help